# Leaflet control not filtering markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to implement a 'filter' feature into my leaflet map alongside marker clusterer, I have got as far as having the control box and plotting the markers however upon unticking a 'category' nothing updates on the map I have attatched an example of which this feature is working http://jsfiddle.net/RogerHN/31v2afte/2/

this is how I plot the marker.

```
    case 'antisocialbehaviour':
    marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {
                icon: icons,
                title: 'antisocialbehaviour'
            });
            markers_cluster.addLayer(marker); 
            break;
```

required code for control box ( top of javascript )

```
var groupA = L.layerGroup(markersA);
var groupB = L.layerGroup(markersB);
var markersA = [];
var markersB = [];
var overlayMaps = {
    "A": groupA,
    "B": groupB
};
L.control.layers(tileLayer, overlayMaps, {position:'topleft'}).addTo(map);
```

My code on JSFiddle if anybody needs to see the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/jgov83fg/25/

Comment: When I untick a category in the JSFiddle you provided, the corresponding marker disappears.

Comment: The first JSFiddle is the JSfiddle i'm working from, the second one (https://jsfiddle.net/jgov83fg/25/) is the one showing the problem ( sorry )

Comment: My bad, I missed the second JSFiddle link.

Comment: So just to be clear, you're trying to hide some of the marker clusters when the user unticks one of the category boxes?

What do category A and category B correspond to in your code? 'antisocialbehaviour' and 'violentcrime'?

Comment: Your'e not adding the markers to marker groups arrays (`markersA` and `markersB`), those layer groups youv'e added are tied to mentioned arrays, which are both empty. You need to add each marker into the apporpiate array.

Comment: Yes, so by default each category will have the tickbox selected by defaut, i Haven't added them all for testing purposes yet, but when unticking a category from the control it will remove that unselected item from the clusterer on the map,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a [copy](https://jsfiddle.net/ivdekov/jgov83fg/36/) of your JSFiddle and made some changes to it.

I included the [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport) sub plugin in the body tag of the JSFiddle's HTML:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster.layersupport@2.0.1/dist/leaflet.markercluster.layersupport.js"></script>
```

I added the following to the JavaScript code:

```
var mcgLayerSupportGroup = L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport(),
  group1 = L.layerGroup(),
  group2 = L.layerGroup(),
  group3 = L.layerGroup(),
  group4 = L.layerGroup(),
  control = L.control.layers(null, null, {
    collapsed: false
  }),
  i, a, title, marker;

mcgLayerSupportGroup.addTo(mymap);

mcgLayerSupportGroup.checkIn([group1, group2, group3, group4]);

control.addOverlay(group1, 'Anti-Social Behaviour');
control.addOverlay(group2, 'Violent Crime');
control.addOverlay(group3, 'Bicycle Theft');
control.addOverlay(group4, 'Burglary');
control.addTo(mymap);

group1.addTo(mymap); // Adding to map or to AutoMCG are now equivalent.
group2.addTo(mymap);
group3.addTo(mymap);
group4.addTo(mymap);
```

Then, in the `create_marker` function, I call either `marker.addTo(group1)`, `marker2.addTo(group2)`, `marker3.addTo(group3)` or `marker4.addTo(group4)` based on the type of the crime the marker is associated with.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I've had a look at your example, but I was hoping to have something along the lines of the first JS fiddle, where unticking an option would remove it from the view and the cluster, the code you have demoed displays the markers on top of the clusters instead of hiding it.

Comment: Oh, okay, I guess I was confused because I didn't see any clusters in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RogerHN/31v2afte/2/). 

So when a user unchecks a checkbox on the layer control box, you want to remove the marker from the marker cluster and have the number on the marker cluster icon decrease. Is that correct?

Comment: Ah, sorry for complicating this! https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/filtering-marker-clusters/ this provides a clustered example. So by defualt the boxes should be ticked. Ticked = Displayed - true, If a used decides they want to hide a crime they an untick the box and it will hide it from the map / cluster. But yes, what you said it correct ! :)

Comment: Take a look at the [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport sub-plugin](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport). It has a link to [this example](https://ghybs.github.io/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport/examples/mcgLayerSupport-controlLayers-realworld.388.html) which I think does exactly what you're looking for. 

I'm still trying to figure out how to get your code to work. You might have better luck.

Comment: I've been trying for a long time. I need to figure out how to separate the markers by category of crime but I've had no avail for quite a long time.

Comment: I think I'm making progress, I'll share something with you soon.

Comment: The leaflet marker support sub plugin looks quite useful, if you can't figure it out I'll give that a shot regardless.

Comment: Genious! When the points are mapped the only issue I'm seeing is onyl anti-social behaviour seems to be showing / hiding let me take a deeper look.

Comment: For 'burglary' it was `marker3.addTo(group4);` instead of `marker4.addTo(group4);`. I updated my answer to include that change.

Comment: i made one slight modification to the javascript located at my save point : https://jsfiddle.net/jgov83fg/43/ the I'm getting the error Uncaught ReferenceError: layerControl is not defined
    at JSON_callback ((index):315)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (requests.js:26) is there a way we can solve this? just to mention it is working as intended just don't want an error there. EDIT: I gave it var layerControl; and it worked fine :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working and that I could help. Hope the project goes well :)